# What are the real world limitations of using a transistor as a switch?

Tags: transistors, switches

I have a circuit where a 5.055V 2.17A (MAX) DC circuit is supposed to be switched using a 3.404V 0.99A(MAX) DC source.

Theoretically, 3.404V 0.99A between base and emitter should allow quite a large current to pass from collector to emitter, but when I am using BC548 B type (Min theoretical gain 200X) as my transistor, the Collector-emitter current that I am actually getting is only about 1.34A.

Of course, BC548 is not designed to handle that high level of current. So I replaced it with TIP31C O Type (Min gain 20X), but something strange hapened with the TIP31C. That transistor is passing at least 1.63A between collector and emitter even when there is nothing connected to base and therefore no potential difference is going on between base and emitter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiodwVm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Admittedly, I do not know how to read all the parameters on a transistor datasheet, but even the BC548 did not break down at that voltage, and there is no OFF characteristic mentioned on the TIP31C datasheet at all.

Not only that, even after applying the 3.404V 0.99A potential difference between base and emitter, the collector-emitter current is only going up to 1.72A.

Is there any theoretical explanation behind this strange behaviour?

Comment: Check the pins you assumed were E, B and C.

Comment: You might be putting 3.4V on the base of the transistor, but if 1A is flowing base to emitter you won't have a transistor for very long.  It is likely to pop and emit smoke if you push that much current through the base of a BC548.

Comment: May I suggest that you have a look around on this site and the rest of the internet to look for information on **how** you should use a transistor to operate a relay. Your schematic will not work because you're using the transistor wrong. There are many ways to do this wrong and only few to do it right. So investigate how others do this and learn from that. Trying to figure it out yourself is almost guaranteed to end in tears. Also, you will learn that you are going to need a flyback diode, without it the transistor will break.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Did I really goof up that bad? I can create a model relay control circuit using BC548 and it works. (I will admit that I had no idea about the flyback diode though) Things go wrong only when I try to implement it in my application. I will try to recreate the whole thing in Fritzing and share it here (I didn't already do it because Fritzing's relays are terrible). Also, that schematic was not supposed to show the proper circuit. It shows the configuration where there should be no connection to the relay, yet the relay is switching.

Comment: Fritzing cartoons won't be greated favourably in all quarters. Show a proper circuit diagram and a picture of what you think you did.

Comment: @Andyaka That was extremely vague and based on personal opinion. Can you explain how to draw a proper circuit diagram?

Comment: Me expressing my personal opinions does not allow you to hold me to the task of explaining how to draw proper circuit diagrams. Go google it. I've given one bit of advice so to expect more might be naive.

Comment: @Andyaka You have merely given an opinion, and I can not be expected to cater to individuals. You gotta tell me why I need anything more professional than Fritzing for my purpose. You haven't even seen my full circuit yet.

Comment: You can do what you want but if you can't take advice then that is something I shan't be worrying about.

Comment: @Andyaka  I guess you were talking about PCB design CAD and EDA tools, SPICE programming, simulators and stuff. Rest assured I am learning to use those, but nothing I have designed so far goes beyond the capabilities of Fritzing. No tool is bad if you know its proper use. It is good to make newcomers aware of the existence of advanced tools, but your way of doing it was unnecessarily vague and personal.

Comment: Even Fritzing can produce a schematic diagram.  The wiring diagrams don't help you understand the circuit.  All they show you is where the wires go.  To see what the circuit is doing, you have to look up the function of each chip and each pin and try to make sense of it. Or, you could use a schematic diagram where all the needed info is readily visible. You might not have gotten beyond Fritzing's limitations yet, but when you do you will have to start all over and learn a new program.  Or, save yourself the hassle and learn a good program first.

Comment: @JRE My current circuit has a NodeMCU in it. It is too complex for SPICE. Even most CADs don't have a footprint for NodeMCU. I'll either have to design one myself or use the community made one for kiCAD. However, due to not having full SPICE data, the design will be no better than the Fritzing diagram. As far as I know, only Proteus can simulate MCUs, but I could not find a NodeMCU for Proteus.

Comment: If Fritzing can make a schematic using your NodeMCU, then that would be as useful as a schematic diagram from any other program.  If all Fritzing can do is to produce a wiring diagram, then that is not useful.  Simulating a microprocessor isn't usually all that useful, either.  You can easily simulate the analog bits around it.

Comment: @JRE T Thx for the idea. I am yet to mess with virtual inputs in SPICE. You see, quite contrary to the tone of Stack Exchange, people who introduced me to electronics had cautioned me about relying on SPICE and EDA tools in general. I was told that debugging using SPICE is only reliable for very trivial circuits. For advanced designs, SPICE should only be used as a sketchbook/ideapad. That is why I did not give it a high priority and still mostly depend on GUI based SPICE tools. As you can see here, I am yet to learn how to properly use a transistor. I will form my own opinion on SPICE later.

Comment: @JRE BTW, certain people are recommending Verilog as a more capable alternative to SPICE. What do you think?

Comment: That Verilog and Spice are two very different animals, and that I've never used Verilog.

Comment: Whether you use Spice directly or in some GUI based tool doesn't matter.  Spice is Spice, and will mislead you if your design doesn't accurately model your real circuit and real parts.  Concentrate on building real circuits that work with real parts - soldered or breadboard whatever as long as it physically exists.  You need a grounding in reality so that you can detect when the simulations are giving you crap results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that configuration, the transistor is an [emitter follower/ common collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector). As such, the maximum voltage the load will ever see is your **3.4V - 0.7V = 2.7V**. Since that's about half what the load expects, it will only take half the current.

Your circuit needs to be [common emitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter), more like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdC3l9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**HOWEVER:** With the load currents you are talking about the base current will be a lot with a simple transistor, likely more than whatever you have driving this can supply. You would be wise to replace Q1 with a suitable N-Channel [MOSFET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) instead.

Obviously, whichever part you chose needs to be able to carry the load current indefinitely without burning out.

Note D1 is a [fly-back diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode). It is required so the transistor does not kill itself when it turns off.

**Leaving the base open**

Not a good idea for any transistor circuit. Leakage current from collector becomes base current. That's why good designs include some form of biasing resistor to hold the base at the right "parked" voltage.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the theory in a very approachable way. Now I see why the transistor is acting like it is blown. That should be enough hints for me to search up the rest.

Comment: I just redesigned the circuit based on the theory you presented, and now it is working flawlessly. Turns out I did not need the TIP31C. BC548 did the job fine. I express my gratitude to all who contributed.

Comment: @Spero thanks for letting us know. It's nice when folks get back, usually we are left hanging.